# how to store a loop over columns in a list with R

Tags: r, list, loops, for-loop, store

Think I have an easy question but I was not able to find my mistake so far.
I want to create a single elimination tournament with 32 participants. To do so I created 4 groups with 8 Players and now a want to build the matchups with a for loop and store them into a list, but its not working as I want :(

```
>groups
            A        B        C        D
    1 Player1  Player9 Player17 Player25
    2 Player2 Player10 Player18 Player26
    3 Player3 Player11 Player19 Player27
    4 Player4 Player12 Player20 Player28
    5 Player5 Player13 Player21 Player29
    6 Player6 Player14 Player22 Player30
    7 Player7 Player15 Player23 Player31
    8 Player8 Player16 Player24 Player32
```

now I want to store them as pairs in their groups to have an easy access to calculate winning props later on.
Should look like this for the first Group A

```
>teams.group.A <- matrix(groups$A,nrow = 2,ncol = 4)
>teams.group.A
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     
[1,] "Player1" "Player3" "Player5" "Player7"
[2,] "Player2" "Player4" "Player6" "Player8"
```

my idea for the loop was:

```
groupnames <- colnames(groups)

mylist <- list()
for(i in groupnames){
  mylist[[i]] <- matrix(groups$i,nrow = 2,ncol = 4)
}
mylist
```

I get the error, that "data" must be a vector type?

Thx, if you can help me here!

Comment: Do you need a `list` as output? Or `data.frame` ok?

Comment: just for purpose of explaining the error: if you use $i , R will not evaluate i. This means it'll directly look for a variable called i in the data frame which is not present. If you use groups[, i] it works, because in this case, i is replaced by its current value. In any case, the solution @Val posted is the way to go as loops are not as preferable in R as in other language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `groups` variable is a dataframe, you can easily use `lapply` and you'll get a nice named list as a result:

```
# generate data
players <- paste0('Player',1:32)
grps <- data.frame(A=players[1:8],B=players[9:16],C=players[17:24],D=players[25:32])


#smoother version as suggested by P Lapointe:
mylist <- lapply(grps,matrix,nrow=2)

# more verbose
# mylist <- lapply(grps,function(x) matrix(x,ncol = 4))


# output

> mylist
$A
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     
[1,] "Player1" "Player3" "Player5" "Player7"
[2,] "Player2" "Player4" "Player6" "Player8"

$B
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      
[1,] "Player9"  "Player11" "Player13" "Player15"
[2,] "Player10" "Player12" "Player14" "Player16"

$C
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      
[1,] "Player17" "Player19" "Player21" "Player23"
[2,] "Player18" "Player20" "Player22" "Player24"

$D
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]      
[1,] "Player25" "Player27" "Player29" "Player31"
[2,] "Player26" "Player28" "Player30" "Player32"
```

To bring it back into a single dataframe, you can use `do.call(cbind,mylist)`:

```
> do.call(cbind,mylist)
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]       [,9]       [,10]      [,11]     
[1,] "Player1" "Player3" "Player5" "Player7" "Player9"  "Player11" "Player13" "Player15" "Player17" "Player19" "Player21"
[2,] "Player2" "Player4" "Player6" "Player8" "Player10" "Player12" "Player14" "Player16" "Player18" "Player20" "Player22"
     [,12]      [,13]      [,14]      [,15]      [,16]     
[1,] "Player23" "Player25" "Player27" "Player29" "Player31"
[2,] "Player24" "Player26" "Player28" "Player30" "Player32"
```

Comment: You can pass the argument to the function like this: `lapply(grps,matrix,nrow=2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can't index with `i` in the loop using `$`, because `i` is a `character`. Try this

```
for (i in groupnames) {
    mylist[[i]] = matrix(groups[[i]], nrow=2, ncol=4)
}
```